# Search engine with few documents just imported

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank, watson

I'm wondering if it's possible to search with the Retrieve and Rank service on few PDF documents you just imported ? Example : I want to search informations on 4 PDF documents, so I import documents in the system and use my search engine to find my informations.

Any idea about the feasibility ?

Answer (score 0):

It'll work - there aren't minimum requirements.

But I'd need to know a little more about your use case to know if it's a sensible idea.

For example, how long are your documents? The smallest production cluster that R&R provides is 32GB, so you'll be paying the monthly fee for that even if you only put 4 tiny documents in. That may not be a very cost-effective way to solve your particular problem.

What do you want it to return in response to queries? If it's the whole document that you want it to return, then every query could end up returning the same 4 documents, just in a different order each time... which doesn't sound like a very helpful thing to do.

Comment: My use case is for searching information in a group of Documents, for example I upload 5 Documents, I ask a question in natural language and It will return the most relevant information.

Comment: That still covers a very broad range of use cases. I'd love to help, but really need more specifics, such as I've described above.  

More specifics about the documents - such as how long are they, what format they are, what language are they in, do they contain images, tables, graphs, etc.  

More specifics about the questions - what sort of questions do you expect?     

More specifics about the desired answers - such as whether you want a whole document returned, or some subset of it, etc.

Comment: It will be documents text, between 5 and 30 pages or more, it will depend of the document. Format is PDF, doc, docx. The language is in my case French, and finally I just want a subset of the text, the quoted result. Example : I ask a question in natural language about something I would like to know in these documents, "Where Sam was living in 2012 ?" and it return the quotation of the answer. I hope my question is more explained.